# probability,permutation &combination

Tags: probability

A deck of 52 playing cards is shuffled, and the cards are turned up one at a time until
the first ace appears. Is the next card—that is, the card following the first ace—more
likely to be the ace of spades or the two of clubs?

Comment: Hint: There are $51!$ ways to order the $51$ cards that aren't the ace of spades. For any one of these, in how many ways can you place the ace of spades such that it immediately follows the first ace?

Comment: if i fix the first card as ace of spades and second card as 2 of cubs then we have 50 ! ways to order

Comment: Above, I meant to suggest a way to find the number of orderings in which the ace of spades immediately follows the first ace. There are $51!$ ways. The same argument works for the number of orderings in which the two of clubs immediately follows the first ace.

Comment: if i fix the first card as ace of spades and second card as 2 of cubs then we have 50 ! ways to order and if i fix first card as ace (no ace of spade) and second card is ace of spade then we have 50! ways  if i fix first card as ace (none ace of spade) and second is 2 of club then we have again 50! ways total=50!%52!+50!%52!+50!%52!=3%(52*51) pls correct me where i am wrong.

Comment: I think you need to do more. What you have above is an ordering in which the first card of the deck is an ace. But the first ace of a deck could be, for example,  the 10th card of the deck (and in this case, with the two of clubs following,  there aren't $50!$ ways to arrange the cards).

Answer (score 1):

Basically, **cards have no preference for positions**, so with the data provided, the ace of spades or the 2 of clubs are equally likely to follow the first ace.

[ In other words, in the absence of information about the other 51 cards, each has a **Pr = 1/51** of being the card after the first ace ]

Comment: The problem statement seems to allow the possibility that the first ace is the ace of spades.  And then...

Answer (score -1):

I'd like to mention one thing: the 2 clubs might appear before the first Ace but the Ace spade has no chance to appear before the first Ace. If the Ace spade appeared before the first Ace, it's the first Ace itself! So the Ace spade has more chance to follow the first Ace than the 2 clubs.